# Hashing (sha1) multiple file concurrently using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sha1, java-7

I have N big files (no less than 250M) to hash. Those files are on P physical drives.

I'd like to hash them concurrently with maximum K active threads but I can not hash more than M files per physical drives because it slows down the whole process (I ran a test, parsing 61 files, and with 8 threads it was slower than with 1 thread; the file were almost all on the same disk).

I am wondering what would be the best approach to this :

- I could use a Executors.newFixedThreadPool(K)
- then I would submit the task using a counter to determine if I should add a new task.

My code would be :

```
int K = 8;
int M = 1;
Queue<Path> queue = null; // get the files to hash
final ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(K);
final ConcurrentMap<FileStore, Integer> counter = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
final ConcurrentMap<FileStore, Integer> maxCounter = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
for (FileStore store : FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()) {
  counter.put(store, 0);
  maxCounter.put(store, M);
}
List<Future<Result>> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
  final Path current = queue.poll();
  final FileStore store = Files.getFileStore(current);
  if (counter.get(store) < maxCounter.get(store)) {
    result.add(newFixedThreadPool.submit(new Callable<Result>() {

      @Override
      public Entry<Path, String> call() throws Exception {
        counter.put(store, counter.get(store) + 1);
        String hash = null; // Hash the file
        counter.put(store, counter.get(store) - 1);
        return new Result(path, hash);
      }

    }));
  } else queue.offer(current);
}
```

Tossing aside the potential non thread safe operation (like how I play with counter), is there a better way to achieve my goal ?

I also think the loop here might be a little too much, as it may take up a lot of process (almost like an infinite loop).

Comment: Do you know which file is on which drive? I'd just allocate one thread per drive, and let it crunch through all the files on that drive.

Comment: Yep, one thread per drive is probably the way to go.

Comment: Yes. In fact, the FileStore stuff gives you the logical drives (which may or may not be a physical drive). Ultimately, I want to run my code a NAS having a RAID of 5 drives which would allow more file to be hashed.

Comment: as a side note use `do{int count = counter.get(store);}while(!counter.replace(store, count,count+1));` instead of the get/put (replace is the CompareAndSwap of the concurrentmap)

Comment: I concur: one per drive prevents head shifts. A priority queue would be nice too, to prevent congestion. Priority based on time in queue and negative file size: like accumulated sizes processed - file size of queue entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much time, I've found a solution to achieve my need: instead of integer counter, or `AtomicInteger` or whatever, I've used an `ExecutorService` and each submitted task use a [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) shared across each file of one drive.

Like:

```
ConcurrentMap<FileStore, Semaphore> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for (Path path : listFile()) {
  final FileStore store = Files.getFileStore(path);
  final Semaphore semaphore = map.computeIfAbsent(store, key -> new Semaphore(getAllocatedCredits(store)));
  final int cost = computeCost(path);
  es.submit(() -> {
    semaphore.acquire(cost);
    try {
      ... some work ...
    } finally {
      semaphore.release(cost);
    }
  });
}


int getAllocatedCredits(FileStore store) {return 2;}
int computeCost(Path path) {return 1;}
```

Notice the help of Java 8, especially in `computeIfAbsent` and `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive hardware configuration is not known at compile time, and may be chaged/upgraded, it's tempting to use a thread pool per drive and make the thread counts user-configurable. I am not famililar with 'newFixedThreadPool' - is the thread count a property that can be changed at run time to optimize performance?

Comment: I simplified my example, but I intended to let the user (myself^^) change the max number of thread (the number of core * 2 if hyperthreading) and the max number of thread per disk.